# How to change first-letter in input html element to uppercase, CSS only

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I am try to get only the first letter on this input element as upper case
`input::first-letter` is not recognize, only `input{text-transform: uppercase;}`

and I try to achieve only value be Hello world  how can I implement it on CSS only?

*that issue happened only on input element

```css
input::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="hello world">
```

https://codepen.io/lichaytiram/pen/JjWmqxo

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN - `::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element.

`<input>` is not a block level element. For example you can see it working for a `<p>` element, which is `block-level`

```css
input {
  display: block; /* still doesn't work */
}

p::first-letter,
input::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="hello world">
<p>hello world</p>
```

Comment: if I add `display: block;` it still not working, How can I fix it?

Comment: @LichayTiram that is the point, it won't work. I put it there with the comment to show that it won't work

Comment: So don't have any way to implement it?

Comment: @LichayTiram you can do this with JavaScript, not with CSS

Comment: oh it so weird should be so easy with CSS, with js the implementation complex?

Comment: *"...should be so easy with CSS"* - there is no way to do it with CSS at the moment. Unless this is implemented for inline elements in future CSS spec...